# Page Title Blur - Title Garbled

Tags: jquery, browser

**Here's what I'm doing:**
I am using this awesome code to change the page title of the browser tab when a user navigates away from my website.

**For example:**
When a user is on my website the title will say "Blakes Seed Based".
When a user navigates away the tab will say something like "Hey! Come back!"

**Here's the issue:** 
The page title is showing up, but so is a bunch of other garbled stuff I have no idea where it's coming from.

**Here's the website (which is in development so you have to use a password to get in:**

URL: https://www.blakesseedbased.com
PASSWORD: *TopSecretPass*

**Here's the code:**

```
// Browser Navigate Away Code
$(function() {

  // Get page title
  var pageTitle = $("title").text();

  // Change page title on blur
  $(window).blur(function() {
     $("title").text('Return to Paradise' + pageTitle);
  });

  // Change page title back on focus
  $(window).focus(function() {
    $("title").text(pageTitle);
  });

});
```

**Here's the Output:**
[image]

Thanks in advance if you have a solution to why this extra garbled stuff is showing up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to your page and played around for a minute in the browser console to locate the issue.

Type `$("title")` into your console and you'll notice it's selecting 10 elements - the initial `<title>` tag in your page `<head>`, and then 9 additional ones hidden in the footer that correspond to Shopify's accepted payment methods.

Since you want to only grab the page title, change this line in your JS:

```
var pageTitle = $("title").text();
```

...to this:

```
var pageTitle = $("head title").text();
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Genius! Thank you, thank you, thank you! This absolutely fixed it :D